# SQL - DELETE some raws from Table1 where some conditions are met on Table2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database where there are 2 Tables: Table1, Table2.

Table1 has this structure:

```
ID, name, description
```

Table2 has this structure:

```
TableID, Metadata, Metavalue
```

Now, I want to delete, from Table1 AND from Table 2 all the rows WHERE Metadata = "Price" AND Metavalue < 200000

This is what I am trying but it does not work:

```
DELETE Table1,  Table2
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.TableID = Table1.ID
WHERE Table2.metadata="Price" AND Table2.Metavalue < 200000
```

Error:

```
Table2: Not unique Table/Alias
```

Where am I wrong?

Note: These tables are pretty big so I am using JOIN since as far as I have learnt it optimizes the resources.

Comment: Carefully read over the query that you posted.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @EzLo I think the OP is using MySQL

Comment: Never mind then, my comment was for SQL Server!

Comment: is `TableID` in Table2 a foreign key to Table1.ID?

Comment: @mahyard: YES. Actually in `Table2` there are multiple rows with the same `TableId` , since they are in fact multiple "metadata" of the same main element, contained in Table1.

Comment: You have `FROM Table2` and `INNER JOIN Table2`. One of these should probably be `Table1`

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of a credible query:

```
DELETE Table1
     , Table2
  FROM Table1
  JOIN Table2 
    ON Table2.TableID = Table1.ID
 WHERE Table2.metadata = "Price" 
   AND Table2.Metavalue < 200000
```

Note that this kind of thing can perhaps be better handled with foreign key constraints